# How to use webpack to bundle library without bundling duplicate react dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm in the process of building a reusable react library that uses other react libraries as dependencies. And I'm using webpack as the build tool.

The challenge that I'm running into is when I import my library into my app, which is built with create-react-app, I get the following error:

```
addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. 
You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, 
or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).
```

The problem, as I understand it, is that webpack is bundling an additional copy of react in my library at a conflicting version.

I've tried several suggestions, but none of them seem to work. I've tried to:

1. Add react as an alias in my webpack

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
    },
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
```

2. Add react and react-dom as externals in webpack:

```
  externals: {
    'ReactCSSTransitionGroup': 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup',
    'react': {
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      umd: 'react',
      root: 'React'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      umd: 'react-dom',
      root: 'ReactDOM'
    }
  },
```

3. Also tried adding react as a devDependency and peerDependency in package.json.

If I delete the node_modules folder while the library is linked up to the app, it starts working. This obviously isn't a solution, but more of a hint that it's pulling in an extra copy of react from the node_modules. As soon as I run `npm i` the problem returns.

Here's my full webpack:

```
const path = require('path')
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

module.exports = {
  entry: SRC_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
    },
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
  },
  externals: {
    'ReactCSSTransitionGroup': 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup',
    'react': {
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      umd: 'react',
      root: 'React'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      umd: 'react-dom',
      root: 'ReactDOM'
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.js?/,
          include: SRC_DIR,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: [
              'transform-class-properties',
              'transform-object-rest-spread'
            ]
          }
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "3.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "4.0.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1"
  }
}
```

I've also created two repos to reproduce the bug, one is the test app, and one is the test library. To reproduce:

1. Clone the app and library and run `npm i`:
   app: https://github.com/scottmcpherson/test-app
   library: https://github.com/scottmcpherson/git-library
2. cd into the library and run `npm link`
3. cd into the app and run `npm link test-library`
4. cd back into the app and run `npm start`
5. You should see the error appear in the browser. If you open the app in the your editor and look App.js you can see where I'm trying to import test-library.

This error only happen because the library depends on `react-bootstrap-table`. If I comment out that module and just render a normal jsx table, everything works find.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication) to avoid dependencies duplication you can try this:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common'
})
```